# Rust: why do I get error [E0507]: cannot move out of `files.input_file` which is behind a shared reference

Tags: rust, ownership

I have narrowed down my real life Rust code to the following:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

struct FileHandler {
    input_file: File,
}

impl FileHandler {
    fn setup(in_file_name: &str) -> Self {
        let i_file = File::open(in_file_name).unwrap();
        Self { input_file: i_file }
    }
}

fn process_file(files: &FileHandler) {
    let lines = BufReader::new(files.input_file).lines();
    for _ln in lines {
        println!("one more line");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let files = FileHandler::setup("foo.txt");
    process_file(&files);
}
```

It does not compile with the message:

```
cannot move out of `files.input_file` which is behind a shared reference
  --> demo.rs:16:32
   |
16 |     let lines = BufReader::new(files.input_file).lines();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `files.input_file` has type `File`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

But precisely, I don't want to make a copy. I just want to use the file I have already checked to be correct. I have tried with mutable references and fields. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
let files = FileHandler::setup("foo.txt");
```

This creates a `FileHandler` struct which stores another struct called `File` in `input_file` property.

`files` struct has the ownership of it's properties. So `files` owns `input_file`.

If you directly use that `input_file` property like this:

```rust
some_function(files.input_file);
```

This means `input_file`'s ownership will be moved to that function.

But if you do this then **what happens if I try to access `files.input_file` again?** Maybe inside of `some_function`, the struct stored in `input_file` property destroyed?

So I can't use it anymore like `files.input_file`.

---

#### Solution:

Use the reference of `input_file`, so it is **borrowed**, not **moved**:

```rust
some_function(&files.input_file);
```

Or in this case of yours:

```rust
BufReader::new(&files.input_file);
```

---

*(btw IMHO I can suggest that you can use `new` instead of `setup`. Creating a struct with some settings often managed by a `new` function. `FileHandler::new()` is much more familiar to Rust devs. Like `BufReader::new()`)*

Comment: Thanks. stupid question get excellent reply...

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, `BufReader::new` is attempting to move `files.input_files`, which is behind a shared reference (`&FileHandler`). In order to have it not move `files.input_file`, use a reference to it instead:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

struct FileHandler {
    input_file: File,
}

impl FileHandler {
    fn setup(in_file_name: &str) -> Self {
        let i_file = File::open(in_file_name).unwrap();
        Self { input_file: i_file }
    }
}

fn process_file(files: &FileHandler) {
    // --- CHANGED ---
    let lines = BufReader::new(&files.input_file).lines();

    for _ln in lines {
        println!("one more line");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let files = FileHandler::setup("foo.txt");
    process_file(&files);
}
```

This happens because [BufReader](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) is generic. If you give it a value, it will move it, if you give it a reference it'll just use the reference instead. Take a look at "[Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html)" from The Book for more information on how ownership works.